# How to Display Image Value in Dropdown using Ionic 2 Dynamically?

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic2

How to  Display Image value in Dropdown Using Ionic 2 Dynamically?

- I'm developing application in Ionic 2. I need to add and display ion-select options in dynamic way, [My Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jgJGtKanIyITvCTD16yV?p=preview) please look at my plunker for reference.
- I have used `ion-select` and `ion-options` to list out the values in dropdown, the values are displaying.
- In Dropdown the image url is displaying but i want to show image in this dropdown.
- Instead of url i want to display image, how can i do this and please suggest and update the plunker as well to know the exact solution...

My data:-

```
<ion-item >
    <ion-label>State</ion-label>
 <ion-select (ionChange)="setDistrictValues(sState)" [(ngModel)]="sState">
      <ion-option [value]="sState" *ngFor = "let sState of states">{{sState.name}}  </ion-option> 
</ion-select>
```

- Please look out [My plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jgJGtKanIyITvCTD16yV?p=preview) for reference, please update my plunker thanks. i don't know where i did the mistake and how to get the solution too...

Comment: Hi all any solution regarding the above question?